# Build failed in Jenkins debian branches

Tags: jenkins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Few days ago i have started the indexing process of our repository in ROS, as well as releasing some packages. Meanwhile i start receiving build erros from jenkins, it seems to be some version issues or a missing debian branches.

When i ran the bloom release, the only complain during the process are some dependencies in the packages. For example, the iai_kinect2, but i had ignored this errors and continuing with the release. Can this cause the missing debian branches in the realese repo and the consequently cause the erros when the jenkins build it?

> <== Failed Could not resolve rosdep
> key 'iai_kinect2' Failed to resolve
> iai_kinect2 on ubuntu:saucy with:
> Error running generator: Failed to
> resolve rosdep key 'iai_kinect2',
> aborting.

```
Started by user Internal
Building remotely on 69.16.195.76 in workspace <http://jenkins.ros.org/job/ros-indigo-forte-rc-teleop_sourcedeb/ws/>
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from git://github.com/ros-infrastructure/buildfarm.git
Checking out Revision 526731d6448065ff1c85e0192ea03e41e692abe1 (origin/master)
[ros-indigo-forte-rc-teleop_sourcedeb] $ /bin/bash /tmp/hudson2223504024597956010.sh
# rosdistro.get_release_build_files() has been deprecated and its functionality is now handled by the 'ros_buildfarm.config' module
Cloning into 'forte_rc_robot-release'...
Branch upstream set up to track remote branch upstream from origin.
<http://jenkins.ros.org/job/ros-indigo-forte-rc-teleop_sourcedeb/ws/output/saucy>: No such file or directory
package name forte_rc_teleop version 1.0.4-0
+ cd <http://jenkins.ros.org/job/ros-indigo-forte-rc-teleop_sourcedeb/ws/workspace> && gbp-clone https://github.com/ingeniarius-ltd/forte_rc_robot-release.git
Fetching targets
+ cd <http://jenkins.ros.org/job/ros-indigo-forte-rc-teleop_sourcedeb/ws/workspace/forte_rc_robot-release> && git tag -l debian/*
No matching tag found. Are you sure you pointed to the right repository or the version is right?, expected debian/ros-indigo-forte-rc-teleop_1.0.4-0_saucy:
 Tags:
No tag; bailing
+ cd <http://jenkins.ros.org/job/ros-indigo-forte-rc-teleop_sourcedeb/ws/workspace/forte_rc_robot-release> && git tag -l debian/*
No matching tag found. Are you sure you pointed to the right repository or the version is right?, expected debian/ros-indigo-forte-rc-teleop_1.0.4-0_trusty:
 Tags:
No tag; bailing
+ cd /tmp/ && ssh rosbuild@repos.ros.org -- rm -rf /tmp/upload/ros-indigo-forte-rc-teleop
+ cd /tmp/n set: && ssh rosbuild@repos.ros.org -- mkdir -p /tmp/upload/ros-indigo-forte-rc-teleop
+ cd /tmp/ && scp -r <http://jenkins.ros.org/job/ros-indigo-forte-rc-teleop_sourcedeb/ws/output/saucy> rosbuild@repos.ros.org:/tmp/upload/ros-indigo-forte-rc-teleop
Failed uploading for distro trusty: Command '['scp', '-r', '<http://jenkins.ros.org/job/ros-indigo-forte-rc-teleop_sourcedeb/ws/output/saucy',> 'rosbuild@repos.ros.org:/tmp/upload/ros-indigo-forte-rc-teleop']' returned non-zero exit status 1
Errors have occurred in the source build see above.
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Build step 'Groovy Postbuild' marked build as failure
Description set:
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222884/build-failed-in-jenkins-debian-branches/) by [Andre Araujo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1209/andre-araujo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2015-12-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2015-12-22**:
Please consider to add more tags to your question to reach more users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, failing to resolve the necessary dependencies might result in not being able to generate the Debian specific branches. Please try to add the missing dependencies to rosdep and redo the bloom release.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2015-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0